# I want my Text Button’s color on Roblox Studio to fade in and fade out but I’m getting error

Tags: lua, roblox

I use Lua Roblox and I was trying to make the text button change color from blue to orange fade out and fade in and my script got an error, so what should I do?

Code:

```
game.StartedGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Color = ””—- I typed orange color inside these brackets —-
wait(.5)
game.StartedGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Color = “”—- I typed blue color inside these brackets—-
```

It is not fading out and in the color is still white. Also, how do I do looping because I don’t want the color to stop changing.

Comment: Please read [ask]. "my script got an error" is not very helpful. What error message?

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you right, you want to have the button background color fading from blue to orange and back in an endless loop? Try putting the following LocalScript below the TextButton.

```
local textButton = script.Parent

local color1 = Color3.fromRGB(128, 128, 255)    -- blue

local color2 = Color3.fromRGB(218, 133, 65)     -- orange

local changeSpeed = 10      -- increase this to make slower 



spawn(function()
    local i = -1
    while true do
        for i=-1,1,1/changeSpeed do
            local f = math.abs(i)
            textButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(
                255 * (color1.r + (color2.r - color1.r) * f), 
                255 * (color1.g + (color2.g - color1.g) * f),
                255 * (color1.b + (color2.b - color1.b) * f)
            )
            wait(0.05)                          
        end
    end
end)
```

Update:

...or use the really cool Tween Service, as Kylaaa mentioned:

```
[...]
local changeSpeed = 1      -- increase this to make slower 

textButton.BackgroundColor3 = color1
local tw = game.TweenService:Create(textButton, TweenInfo.new(changeSpeed, Enum.EasingStyle.Sine, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, -1, true), { BackgroundColor3 = color2 })
tw:Play()
```

Comment: This interpolation code is written really clearly, but you can achieve the same effect without needing to do the math yourself with a Tween : https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tween

Comment: That is pretty cool. I'm fairly new to Roblox, I didn't know about that mechanism. I update the answer and hope I used it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
game.StartedGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Color = ””—- I typed orange color inside these brackets —-
wait(.5)
game.StartedGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Color = “”—- I typed blue color inside these brackets—-
```

`TextButton` has no `Color` porperty.

See https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TextButton

Fading is not achieved by switching from one to another color with a 500ms delay. You have to code a smooth transition between both colors.

It's either `BackgroundColor3` or any of the other color properties listed there.

Assigning a string doesn't make too much sense and also might cause an error.
You have to assign a [Color3](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Color3) datatype.

Answer (score 0):

game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(color1)
wait(.5)
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(color2)